# Create a customized default entry in a input box of a NewForm.aspx based on total count (increment)

Tags: newform, default-value, auto-increment, splist-custom-newform

New at creating JavaScript Code in SharePoint.

I'm trying to create a customize default value input on my NewForm.aspx.

It's based on counting the number of entries so far (including 0) and then taking that value, add with some text ("RT-1" for example) and have it the default value for the next entry, so it will be incremental.  Also, I'll have to create a condition that, if there are no items in a list that it starts at 0 count.  Is this possible?  Here's what I wrote so far but nothings working:

```
<script src="/siteassets/jsLib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$SP().list("FormTest").get({fields:"ID"}, function(data) {
  var countData=data.length;
$("input[Title='AutoNumb Required Field']").val("RT-"+countData);

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible provided you run an additional method first that returns the count of entries in that particular list, more specifically a synchronous REST API call. In case the list entries are blank, it can start from 0 as per your requirement. Here is the code below -

```
<script src="/siteassets/jsLib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var countData = getListEntryCount("FormTest")

 $SP().list("FormTest").get({fields:"ID"}, function(data) {
       $("input[Title='AutoNumb Required Field']").val("RT-"+countData);

  });

function getListEntryCount(listname)
{
    var totalEntries = 0;
    var myURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(' "+ listname +" ')/Items?$top=5000";
    $.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    async: false,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
            totalEntries = data.d.results.length;
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
return totalEntries;
}

</script>
```

Comment: I thanks for your quick reply.  I tried it but for some reason, the value isn't showing up in the textbox of my form.  Is my portion of the code correct specifically 
"function(data) {" //sixth line?

Comment: try using alerts if you are getting the count first.. use alert(countData) after the 2nd line and see..

Comment: yeah, alerts not even working so I may have to look at why my script isn't running.  The only thing is if just add $("input[Title='AutoNumb Required Field']".val("RT-"+1);, it will show.

Comment: I was finally able to get the above to work.  Just forgot to add function keyword. 
 Then modified it a bit to get the last entry'd ID number then just do an increment from that.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: glad it worked! do upvote this answer :)